# Stopping repetition of words within a word in a text/abrreviation translator using HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of words that I wish to be translated which is functioning. However, when I translate certain longer words, as an example 2moro translates to Tomoareareow rather than tomorrow as the two 'r's in tomorrow are translated after 2moro has been translated. Is there a way of fixing this so that when someone puts '2moro' in or other text abbreviation words that the actual translation is given, but words such as 'b', 'r', and 'u' aren't translated within the word. However I still need the translator to be able to translate the letters on their own. As this is a very particular request, I couldn't see anything similar around, but I think there must be a way? Obviously there  are many text abbreviations you could test I just have some examples.

this is the code involved and some extra to show the scripts running the translator. I have a CSS style sheet as well+ the rest of the HTML&JavaScript code but I don't think it is necessary for this problem, although please tell me if it is! :

```
<div class="lightgrey">
    <input type= "text" cols="40" rows="2" class="textbox"  
id="textbox1" value= "ENTER TRANSLATION HERE" onfocus="textdelete(this)" 
    text maxlength="80"> </input>
    <br> <p>
    <div class="buttonbox"> <button onclick="word()"> Transl8te it </button>  </div>
<br>
<input type="text" class="textbox" id="textbox2" value= "Translation should appear here" disabled> </input>
</div>  
<script>
var repeat= [  
[/txt/gi, "text"],
[/2moro/gi, "Tomorrow"], 
[/2nite/gi, "Tonight"], 
[/BRB/gi, "Be Right Back"],
[/m8/gi, "Mate"], 
[/IKR/gi, "I Know Right"],
[/BTW/gi, "By The Way"], 
[/B4N/gi, "Bye For Now"], 
[/BCNU/gi, "Be Seeing You"], 
[/BFF/gi, "Best Friends Forever"], 
[/CYA/gi, "See Ya"], 
[/DBEYR/gi, "Don't Believe Everything You Read"], 
[/FWIW/gi, "For What It's Worth"], 
[/giR8/gi, "Great"],
[/ILY/gi, "I Love You"], 
[/IMHO/gi, "In My Humble Opinion"], 
[/IRL/gi, "In Real Life"], 
[/ISO/gi, "In Search Of"], 
[/JK/gi, "Just Kidding"],
[/L8R/gi, "Later"], 
[/LMAO/gi, "Laughing My Ass Off"], 
[/LOL/gi, "Laughing Out Loud"], 
[/LYLAS/gi, "Love You Like A Sister"], 
[/MHOTY/gi, "My Hat's Off To You"], 
[/NIMBY/gi, "Not In My Back Yard"], 
[/NP/gi, "No Problem"], 
[/NUB/gi, "New person to a site or game"], 
[/OMG/gi, "Oh My God"],
[/OT/gi, "Off Topic"],
[/POV/gi, "Point Of View"], 
[/RBTL/gi, "Read Between The Lines"], 
[/ROTFLMAO/gi, "Rolling On The Floor Laughing My Ass Off"],  
[/THKS/gi, "Thanks"], 
[/SH/gi, "Sh** Happens"], 
[/SITD/gi, "Still In The Dark"], 
[/SOL/gi, "Sooner Or Later"], 
[/STBY/gi, "Sucks To Be You"],  
[/RTM/gi, "Read The Manual"],  
[/RTFM/gi, "Read The F***ing Manual"],
[/TLC/gi, "Tender Loving Care"], 
[/TMI/gi, "Too Much Information"], 
[/TTYL/gi, "Talk To You Later"], 
[/TYVM/gi, "Thank You Very Much"],   
[/WTF/gi, "What The F***"],
[/WYWH/gi, "Wish You Were Here"],
[/YOLO/gi, "You Only Live Once"],
[/WYD/gi, "What are you doing"],
[/AFK/g, "Away from the keyboard"],
[/4U/gi, "For you"],
[/B4N/gi, "By for now"],
[/BBL/gi, "Be back later"],
[/BDAY/gi, "Birthday"],
[/CBA/gi, "Can't be asked"],
[/CU/gi, "See you"],
[/transl8/gi, "Translate"],
[/cud/gi, "could"],
[/r/gi, "are"],
[/u/gi, "you"] 

]

function word() {
var text= document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
for (var i=0; i<repeat.length;i++) {
text= text.replace(repeat[i][0], repeat[i][1]); 
} 
document.getElementById("textbox2").value=text  
}

function textdelete(x) {
if (x.value=="ENTER TRANSLATION HERE"){
x.value="";
};
}
</script>
```

Thankyou.

Comment: I did try a Js fiddle but when I press run it doesn't work so i'll work on it and try and post one soon if that heps

Comment: One thing you could do is wrap each regular expression in word boundaries (`\b`) which will prevent any of them being replaced as part of another word. So instead of `/2moro/gi` you have `/\b2moro\b/gi`. Not sure if that's what you're really looking for.

Comment: @Ben wouldn't /\b2moror\b/gi mean 'b2moro' is translated rather than just '2moro'?

Comment: No, `\b` is not a literally 'b' character, it's a word boundary, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html.

Comment: actually that might work, ill check it out- thanks

Comment: Yes I think that works! exactly what I wanted; if you want to post that as an answer I will approve it and get you some more experience points :)

Comment: Done. :) As an aside, if you want to improve your code you should change your array into an object like `var repeat = { 'txt': 'text', '2moro': 'tomorrow', 'etc': 'etcetera' }` and then when you loop through the object (with a `for (var prop in repeat)` loop) you can create the regular expression by doing `new RegExp('\b' + prop + '\b', 'gi')`.

Comment: @ben i'm not quite sure how to go about the var prop in repeat thing , I know what you are trying to suggest I do; it would be easier to add more terms on if I did that but i'm not sure what a for loop is, as i'm not too experienced :(

Comment: Well if you had an object like I showed before, then instead of `for (var i=0; i<repeat.length;i++) text= text.replace(repeat[i][0], repeat[i][1])` you would have something like `for (var t in repeat) text = text.replace(new RegExp('\b' + t + '\b', 'gi'), repeat[t])`. Hope that gives you the gist of it.

Comment: @ben yep I think I get it- ill work on it later now i'm busy for a bit. thanks very much for your help, you've sorted basically all my problems :)

Comment: @Ben is the t significant or can it be any letter? the same goes for new RegExp?

Comment: `t` is a variable and can be changed to whatever you like (I only used `t` to make it shorter in the comment), but `new RegExp` must remain the same.

Comment: @ ben sorry I'm still not getting it! does the `in repeat` refer to `var repeat = {` ? and if so what does `in` do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @ ben so it gives you the what you type in the box now but doesn't actually translate anymore? any ideas, I'm still a bit confused by all this new `RegExp` thing, as of yet I haven't managed to successfully implement it, can you tell me anymore to get it working? thanks again, sorry for pestering you :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/45R68/

Comment: ah ok I ha done it right except I forgot the two \\ (I only used 1) `function word() {
 var text= document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
 for (var t in repeat){ 
        text = text.replace(new RegExp('\b' + t + '\b', 'gi'), repeat[t]); }
   document.getElementById("textbox2").value=text 
   } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap each regular expression in word boundaries (`\b`) which will prevent any of them being replaced as part of another word. So for example, instead of `/2moro/gi` you have `/\b2moro\b/gi`.